# How to Clone a Managed App to Edit the Utility Bar?

Tags: managed-package

I'd like to add some functionality to the *Utility Bar* for a managed app. Being that it's managed, I cannot edit the *Utility Bar* (see image below). I've seen that it's possible however, as there's a way to clone the managed app with a new name. The clone becomes unmanaged and you can make desired changes. How do you clone an app? All of my searching only leads to the Salesforce community asking for this functionality from within *Setup*.

[image: Salesforce]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Setup > Lightning App Builder there should be a clone link beside the apps that you can click to clone the app

[image]